# how to connect oracle database with c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g

I am trying to get connection with Oracle database but there is an error that shows that data source not found! Please can anyone help?

```
string ConnectionString= "Data Source=voldemort-pc;User ID=student;Password=***********;Unicode=True";

OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("success!");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use ODBC instead of the native [Oracle ADO.NET provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) ?

Comment: Are you using a 64bit or 32bit operating system?

Comment: i am very amature. how do i use oracle ado.net instead of odbc? i am using 32 bit operating system

Comment: Are you sure `voldemort-pc` is the name assigned to the **database**? Looks like it might be the name of the server instead.

Comment: i use this data source name from my visual studio connection string property where voldemort is my computer name

Comment: i am not finding this dll file System.Data.OracleClient in my visual studio

Comment: latter i browse this file and it is not loaded in my visual studio 10